# MySQL, group by is not respecting order by

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        wtb_orders.orderid,
        wtb_orders.duration,
        wtb_orders.is_renew,
        wtb_orders.bundle_id,
        wtb_orders.service_id,
        wtb_orders.object_name,
        wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk,
        expires,
        wtb_tokens.disconnect_time
    FROM wtb_orders
    JOIN wtb_tokens ON wtb_orders.orderid=wtb_tokens.orderid
    WHERE 
        wtb_orders.username= "11111111111" AND
        (
            (
                ((expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW()) OR 
                (expires=0 AND wtb_tokens.orderid IS NOT NULL)
            ) OR
            expires=0
        )
    ORDER by expires DESC
) as tmp
GROUP BY 
    tmp.pkg_id_fk, 
    tmp.bundle_id,
    tmp.service_id;
```

I want to order by `expires`, then select distinctly the items having either of the `tmp.pkg_id_fk, tmp.bundle_id,tmp.service_id` not null.

Should 2 items have the same `bundle_id` for example, I want to select the one with the more recent `expires` date.

the query should work, If I don't put `group by` everything is good, I use the group by to filter out duplicates and it decides to pick one with an old expires date, as if I didn't sort them.

Sorry for the delay in providing an example, This is an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=677a69a0445690e0014745391771df1b)

So in the first select query I select everything and in the second select query I use group by, just so you could see the difference. Just look at the items which have `pkg_id_fk = 35`

When I do the group by, I expect to see the one with max expires date But instead, I see another one.

The reason is, suppose you bought a bundle, it's about to expire so you renewed it, now you have two duplicate bundles. I want to let you see the newest one.

Comment: I tried using max, order by and then group by, it didn't work, I started seeing `max(expires)` in the api response but other than that, it didn't do anything

Comment: Did you try order by after group by?

Comment: @PrakharLondhe yes, with one select not 2 selects, same issue, I only used two selects to try and force mysql to respect the order, didn't help

Comment: This is not a good question. Well for me it is not. You are asking something and you are not giving us any example data ? In few min time I have created this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa11d87dd94ef363fc31e9d8b9bc8dbe where you can see you can order by expires in a  simple query. What is your question ? Show us your data you start with. Show us your expected results and then maybe we can help.

Comment: Also, when you are using group by you need to add all the columns you have selected, if they are not part of some aggregation function, in the group by clause. This is something you could found in 1000000 of places. Here is example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=953150da44bf662b76424b7dac09471b

Comment: @VBoka Unless I misunderstood the first example, it's different than what I'm trying to run.  What im trying to do is  this: My query might return duplicates. If there are duplicate `pkg_id_fk or `bundle_id`  or `service_id` then I want to select the one having the  newer expire date only

Comment: I just want to show, with that example, that we do not know what you need without any data.

Comment: @VBoka, no problem, few minutes and I'll prepare an example

Comment: Great, try to put it in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 And then after you fill that share the link of that fiddle in your question and add example of what is it you expect to get as result.

Comment: @VBoka please see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209951/discussion-between-vboka-and-lynob).

Comment: It's very clear that you are misunderstanding both how GROUP BY and ORDER BY work and because you are using an older version of mysql that allows you to not include non-aggregated columns you are getting bizarre results. In short. If you are not aggregating the column with a formula like `SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc then it MUST be listed in your group by. Every other RDBMS on the planet would throw an error with this SQL but older version of mysql will give you enough rope to hang yourself with.

Comment: @JNevill listing all columns in group by? what good would that do? I need to group_by  pkg_id, for example, to remove the duplicates, if I group by expire too, I reintroduce the duplicates. Could you please show an example?

Comment: Your almost there... if you are going to include `expire` in your `SELECT` then it MUST be wrapped in an aggregate formula or included in the `GROUP BY`.  Like `SELECT pkg_id, MAX(expire) FROM yourtable GROUP BY pkg_id;`. Essentially you want a record for each unique `pkg_id`, but if multiple records exist for that unique `pkg_id` and each has a different `expire` then you must specify, by way of an aggregate formula, which `expire` value you want. In this example I want the `max` expire. If don't specify it will return a random `expire` out of the multiple options it must choose from. Yuck.

Comment: See if "groupwise-max" is what you are trying to do.  I added a tag for such.  Also, see my blog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: Also:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share an answer I received on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/flhuux/mysql_group_by_is_not_respecting_order_by/fkyud5l?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) by `GreenPilgrim89`, it's a brilliant answer, I don't like to use it in production though, because it's hacky, unless there's no other option. He says just add limit to enforce the order, and it worked!

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        wtb_orders.orderid,
        wtb_orders.duration,
        wtb_orders.is_renew,
        wtb_orders.bundle_id,
        wtb_orders.service_id,
        wtb_orders.object_name,
        wtb_orders.pkg_id_fk,
        expires,
        wtb_tokens.disconnect_time
    FROM wtb_orders
    JOIN wtb_tokens ON wtb_orders.orderid=wtb_tokens.orderid
    WHERE 
        wtb_orders.username= "11111111111" AND
        (
            (
                ((expires + INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= NOW()) OR 
                (expires=0 AND wtb_tokens.orderid IS NOT NULL)
            ) OR
            expires=0
        )
    ORDER by expires DESC LIMIT 1000000 
) as tmp
GROUP BY 
    tmp.pkg_id_fk, 
    tmp.bundle_id,
    tmp.service_id;
```

For more info check [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) and his post linked above.